# Function of strings to tibble

Tags: r, parsing, tibble

I need to define a function `f(x,y)` such that:

```
x = "col1,1,2,3,4"
y = "col2,a,b,c,d"
```

becomes:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
   col1  col2
  <int> <chr>
1     1     a
2     2     b
3     3     c
4     4     d
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: please post what you've already done to try to solve the issue!

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious idea that comes to mind is to split the input by comma, use `paste` to combine the output into a single string, and read that using `read_csv`.

Example:

```
paste(do.call(paste, c(strsplit(c(x, y), ","), sep = ", ")), collapse = "\n")
# [1] "col1, col2\n1, a\n2, b\n3, c\n4, d"

library(tidyverse)
read_csv(paste(do.call(paste, c(strsplit(c(x, y), ","), sep = ", ")), collapse = "\n"))
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#    col1 col2 
#   <int> <chr>
# 1     1 a    
# 2     2 b    
# 3     3 c    
# 4     4 d
```

From there, I hope you're able to convert the approach to a function.